# VBScript - Passing Objects into a sub or function

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to pass two objects into a function, but get an error saying "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'space'

I am able to manipulate these objects (`Object1` and `Object2`), but can't figure out how to pass them into a function.

```
Sub OnFormat

Dim Object1
Dim Object2

Set Object1 = rpt.Sections("Details").Controls("txtManufacturer")
Set Object2 = rpt.Sections("Details").Controls("Label36")



'Call Position(Object1,Object2)

'End Sub

'Sub Position(Object1,Object2)

If Object1.text = "" then 
 Object2.Visible = false 
 Object1.Visible = false 
else
 Object2.Top = space
 Object1.Top = space
 Object2.Visible = true 
 Object1.Visible = true
End If

End Sub
```

The following code works without a problem, but when the comments are put in I get the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a dangling "End Sub", you need a Class definition, and the object variables need a "New ClassName" expression. So start with something like:

```
Option Explicit

Class cClass
  Public m_Prop
End Class ' cClass

Dim Object1
Dim Object2

Set Object1 = New cClass
Set Object2 = New cClass
Call Func(Object1,Object2)
WScript.Echo Object1.m_Prop, Object2.m_Prop

Sub Func(Object1,Object2)
  Object1.m_Prop = "A"
  Object2.m_Prop = Object1.m_Prop & "B"
End Sub
```

output:

```
A AB
```

**Update:**

A sure way to get the error you mentioned is:

> > s = Space()
> >
> > Error Number:       450
> >     Error Description:  Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

so check your other code for illegal use of the Space() function.

Where the objects come from and whether you have access to the class definition has nothing to do with passing them to a function/sub.

**Update II:**

*Don't use 'space' as a variable name (it clashed with the function of that name).*

Comment: I forgot the Sub at the beginning. I'm trying to use an object that has already been created. Object1 and 2 are components that I can change the properties of, I just want to know how to pass them into a routine.

Comment: @AlGJohnston - my code demonstrates exactly that: the objects are passed into Func(), changed there, and the modification is shown in the top level WScript.Echo statement. The error you get is caused by code you didn't publish.

Comment: The problem is that the components are prebuilt by the program I'm using, so I don't have the class where the objects came from.

Comment: I don't have an s's laying around. I'm going to repost my exact code.

Comment: @AlGJohnston - Space() is a function; so don't use "space" as a variable name.